# SSD died, it had grub/Win10/boot, but HDD has linux, how to recover?

Tags: 16.04, grub2

I had two disks in a tower workstation, one SSD (grub,Windows10, /boot)  and one secondary spinning disk HDD with ubuntu 16.04 desktop on that HDD.

The SSD died at boot after three years of operation.

The HDD has ubuntu 16.04 desktop partitions which are clean and all files intact (checked HDD on other system), partitions for / (includes /home) and /swap. I have recent backups of /home.

I don't care about the loss of Win10 as I rarely used it, but I'd like to be able to boot into the ubuntu 16.04, if that is possible.

I fitted a new blank SSD, which is configured as the boot drive.

What can I do , if anything, to get grub on the blank SSD and /boot and try to start the ubuntu that is on the HDD on /dev/sdb4? (The HDD never had a bootable partition, as the system booted from SSD into grub which had options for ubuntu and Win10). From another system, I can see that the /etc/fstab on the HDD references /boot/efi with a UUID that no longer exists ( i.e /dev/sda1 on the dead SSD was /boot/efi vfat) as the ubuntu on the HDD had been installed from DVD some years ago.

I know I can install a new copy of ubuntu on the SSD, and it can "see" the /dev/sdb4 which is on the SDD under /media/...., but I would prefer to be able to re-use the pre-existing ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new ESP - efi system partition on either drive and do a total uninstall/reinstall of grub. Be sure to partition drive with gpt(GUID) partitioning, not old MBR(msdos).

Often easier to use Boot-Repair & its advanced mode to choose install & which drive's ESP to use.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &

https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only wants to install to first drive, sda or first NVMe drive, but grub can be installed to any drive. I like to have an ESP on every drive, even if just as a backup of my main ESP and may still need a repair to work.

UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:

[How to prepare a disk on an EFI based PC for Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu)

Note that 16.04 reaches EoL - end of life early next year, so need to start planning on 18.04 or 20.04 install. I prefer to have / on SSD and data on HDD. But after installing new larger SSD, I now have most data on SSD, and HDD is more for backup. But no Windows to confuse things.